# How to draw a border around an NSTexturedSquareBezelStyle button

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I noticed the other day that one of my web pages was looking ugly. The buttons on the page looked [totally different](http://jsbin.com/tinefuweco/1/), based on whether they contained one line of text or two.

After some digging, I've learned that the typical button uses `NSRoundedBezelStyle`, but it has a fixed height. So, if the text is going to wrap, Firefox (and Chrome and Safari) will [change the button to use `NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/cocoa/nsNativeThemeCocoa.mm#1191) which can have a variable height. I'd like to petition the maintainers of these browsers to change this and am researching the best alternative.

After finding the [already-filed bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805593) and doing some reading, I suggested that maybe they could use `NSTexturedSquareBezelStyle` instead. It turns out that in Mavericks it looks almost exactly the same as an `NSRoundedBezelStyle` button. Same in Yosemite, except that it has no border. Changing `setBordered` has no effect.

So my question, on behalf of browser developers everywhere: **is it possible to draw an `NSTexturedSquareBezelStyle` button with a border**? Or, is there another way around this that all the browser vendors have missed?

Answer (score 3):

**Rewritten Answer**

I'm not seeing an `NSTexturedSquareBezelStyle` button showing up borderless in Yosemite:

[image: NSTexturedSquareButonStyle button under Yosemite.]

This is a stock button dragged from the palette in Interface Builder. I encourage you to post your code since it's likely you're generating your button in code. Here's my own code for generating the same button:

```
NSButton * anotherButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
anotherButton.bezelStyle = NSTexturedSquareBezelStyle;
anotherButton.title = @"Line 1\nLine 2";
```

Proof:

[image: Same button created with code.]

If you're seeing different results under Yosemite, you'll need to post your code. At a guess, you might be initializing your button with `-init` instead of `-initWithFrame:`, which can cause all kinds of drawing issues since `NSButton` is an `NSView` and therefore its designated initializer is `-initWithFrame:`. Just a guess though.

Comment: There is a very slight border, but not enough to provide contrast against a white background, or light coloured image. In Mavericks, this button looked exactly like a normal button, which was what I was hoping for. It's just frustrating that there's such an obvious limitation that Apple hasn't addressed in their APIs.

Comment: Aside from the ability to subclass the button cell and override its drawing, of course. ;-)